# Why function model.predict() doesn't free RAM memory?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, teachable-machine

Function model.predict() doesn't free it's memory. Every literation of loop it takes more and more RAM.Im trying that on Ubuntu 22.04 with Conda env.

Keras model is created via teachablemachine from google.

Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
import keras # TensorFlow is required for Keras to work
import cv2  # Install opencv-python
import numpy as np

np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)


model = keras.models.load_model('ml_files/model_lid.h5',compile=False)

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(2)

while True:
    ret, image = camera.read()

    image = cv2.resize(image, (224, 224), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

    cv2.imshow("Webcam Image", image)

    image = np.asarray(image, dtype=np.float32).reshape(1, 224, 224, 3)

    image = (image / 127.5) - 1

    model.predict(image)

    keyboard_input = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if keyboard_input == 27:
        break
 
    del image

    keras.backend.clear_session()


camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I comment model.predict(), RAM is stable.
Even `keras.backend.clear_session()` can't clear that.

Comment: Any luck so far?

Answer (score 0):

This was a struggle for me as well. A few thing you could try:

1. use garbage collection after each call with `gc.collect()`
2. Call the prediction with `model(image, training=False)`